# R package creation questions

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I want to create an R package, but I'm completely new in this topic, and even though I've already checked some excellent resources like Hadley Wickham's [R packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), I've a couple of questions that I'd like to clarify:

1. Do I need to import the `stats` package to make use of the `lm` function?
2. How can I make use of the piping operator `%>%` in the `magrittr` package since I can not write `library(magrittr)`?
3. If I created a function that is for utility purposes but it shouldn't be available to the end user, how can I hide it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to import the stats package to make use of the lm function?

No.  It's loaded automatically.  You only need to import for packages not loaded when R boots (like lattice)

> How can I make use of the piping operator %>% in the magrittr package
>   since I can not write library(magrittr)?

I'd import it as Hadley does [HERE](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/bd372a4d625b225a40354a9a091b9185c7736dae/R/utils.r) in dplyr:

```
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @name %>%
#' @export
#' @rdname chain
#' @usage lhs \%>\% rhs
NULL
```

If you're not using **roxygen2** to document I'd really recommend it, but if you're reading Hadley's tutorial you probably will go that route.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tyler-rinker for your reply! One last question: if I created a function that is for utility purposes but it shouldn't be available to the end user, how can I hide it?

Comment: It is hidden automatically. Only functions that you explicitly **export** are directly visible to the user. Using `roxygen`, you do this using ´@export`.

Comment: Your HERE link is dead, btw. Maybe you want this one https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/bd372a4d625b225a40354a9a091b9185c7736dae/R/utils.r