# Error in as(data, "transactions"): no method or default for coercing “data” to “transactions”

Tags: r, arules

Within a little script I wrote, I successfully call

```
library(arules)
trans <- as(data, "transactions")
```

Now I want to include this in a function in my R package. `arules` is imported, and I call the arules functions using `::`. However, `as` does not work. It gives me the above error message, which suggests that it does not know how to handle `transactions`. And there is no `as.transactions`, or similar in the `arules` package that I could import.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394736/823098) shows how to import an operator from a package. I assume there is something similar for my problem, I just don't know what to look for.

What do I have to do in order for `as` to understand what `transactions` are?

Comment: `as` redirects to `as.transactions` if such a function exists. If you want `as` to work here, you must write a function named that (consistent with whatever object-oriented stuff is required). Maybe you should just use whatever constructor there is for transactions instead of coercing.

Comment: Like I said, there is no `as.transactions` defined anywhere. The functionality is achieved implementing a `setAs` function. See my answer below for details.

Comment: Ok, nice find. This is over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, I found the answer in Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports). `transactions` is an S4 class, as can be seen in `arules`' [source](https://github.com/mhahsler/arules/blob/master/R/AllClasses.R). To import an S4 class, we simply put a roxygen-style `@importClassesFrom` above the head of the function we are using the class in.

```
#' @importClassesFrom arules transactions
```

One might also have to add the `methods` package to the imports, as the S4 functionality is implemented there.