# Questions about R package publishing and code visibility

Tags: r, package, cran

When I use a package in R I install it and use it with loading it. Now what if I add a package which uses another package? Is this package automatically downloaded and loaded too? Or is it in general forbidden for a R package to use another package? I don't think that.

Suppose I want to publish a R package. Within my code, can I use functions from other packages and install and load these packages? Or how does this work when I need functions from other packages? Do I have to implement a message that this and that package is needed and that the user has to install and load it prior to it and I need to implement error catching functions in case the package cannot be found on the pc system?

When I want to publish a R package, can I use/call Java code within my package/code?

For a package which was already published - so let's take just as an example the fGarch package - I would like to see the complete code. How can I see this? I know that R is open source and I think it is more or less possible to just enter a function empty and get the code displayed, but sometimes this does not work and especially my question is: Is there a way I can look into the whole code of the package?

For a package which was already published, is it possible to see and look into all files which were submitted? So like a repository as git where all files are submitted - the code itself and further files which are needed like description files or whatever - and I can see these files and look into them?

Furthermore regarding [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393556/r-package-creation-questions) and hiding functions: Is there code in a R package which I cannot see as an end user? This refers also to my previous question, how can I or which way can I see the whole code in a R package?

Comment: You seem to want to get serious about making a package! You may have a look here : http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ (this helped me a lot when creating my first package)

Comment: (1) *"Java code"*, see [`rJava`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html).  (2) *"see the complete code"*: I often to go to https://github.com/cran to look at source for individual packages' source code, and many packages list their github/gitlab/r-forge repo on their CRAN package page. (3) *"code ... which I cannot see"* is often a problem with S4 and `R6` OOP code, and certainly with compiled code (C, C++, `Rcpp`), but if you have concerns over hiding proprietary code then R may not be your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have a few different questions here. Let's take them in the order you asked them:

> **What if I add a package which uses another package? Is this package automatically downloaded and loaded too? Or is it in general forbidden for a R package to use another package?**

It is certainly not forbidden for an R package to use another R package. In fact, the majority of R packages *rely* on other packages.

The source code for each R package must include a text-based `DESCRIPTION` file in the root directory. In this file you will find (among other things) a "Depends" field, and an "Imports" field. Together, these two fields list all the other packages *required* to use *this* package. If a user doesn't already have these other packages installed in their local library, R will install them automatically when it installs the requested package.

If your package lists a dependency in "Depends", then the dependency package is *attached* whenever your package is attached. Thus if you looked at the source code for a package called "foo" and you see that its `DESCRIPTION` file contains the line

```r
Depends: bar,
```

you know that when you call `library(foo)` in your R console, you have effectively done `library(bar); library(foo)`

This isn't always ideal. The package `foo` might only need a couple of functions from package `bar`, and `bar` might contain some other functions whose names could clash with other commonly used functions. Therefore, in general, if you are writing a package and you only want to use a few functions from another package, it would be better to use "Imports" rather than "Depends" to limit the number of unnecessary symbols being added to your user's search path.

---

> **Suppose I want to publish a R package. Within my code, can I use functions from other packages and install and load these packages**

Yes, you can use functions from other packages. The simplest way to do this is to include the name of the package in the `Depends` field of your `DESCRIPTION` file.

However, when using just a few functions from another package inside your own package, best practice is to use the "Imports" field in the `DESCRIPTION` file, and use a namespace qualifier for the imported function in your actual R code. For example, if you wanted to use `ggplot` from the `ggplot2` package, then inside your function you would call it `ggplot2::ggplot` rather than just `ggplot`.

If you publish your package for others to use, the dependencies will be installed automatically along with your package if the user calls `install.packages` with the default settings. For example, when I did:

```
install.packages("fGarch")
```

I got the associated message:

```
#> also installing the dependencies ‘timeSeries’, ‘fBasics’, ‘fastICA’
```

---

> **Do I have to implement a message that this and that package is needed and that the user has to install and load it prior to it and I need to implement error catching functions in case the package cannot be found on the pc system?**

No, not in general. R will take care of this as long as you have listed the correct packages in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

---

> **When I want to publish a R package, can I use/call Java code within my package/code?**

R does not have a native Java API, but you can use your own Java code via the [rJava package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html), which you can list as a dependency for your package. However, there are some users who have difficulty getting Java to run, for example business and academic users who may use R but do not have Java installed and do not have admin rights to install it, so this is something to bear in mind when writing a package.

---

> **For a package which was already published - so let's take just as an example the fGarch package - I would like to see the complete code. How can I see this?**

Every package available for download from CRAN has its source code available. In the case of `fGarch`, its [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/) contains a link to the gzipped tarball of the source code. You can download this and use `untar` in R to review all the source code. Alternatively, many packages will have an easily-found repository on Github or other source-control sites where you can examine the source code via a browser. For example, you can browse the fGarch source on Github [here](https://github.com/cran/fGarch).

---

> **For a package which was already published, is it possible to see and look into all files which were submitted? So like a repository as git where all files are submitted - the code itself and further files which are needed like description files or whatever - and I can see these files and look into them?**

Yes, you can look at all the sources files for all the packages uploaded to CRAN on Github at the unofficial Github CRAN mirror [here](https://github.com/cran)

---

> **Is there code in a R package which I cannot see as an end user? This refers also to my previous question, how can I or which way can I see the whole code in a R package?**

As above, you can get the source code for any package via CRAN or Github. As you said, you can look at the source code for *exported* functions just by typing the name of that function into R. For unexported functions, you can do the same with a triple colon. For example, `ggplot2:::adjust_breaks` allows you to see the function body of the unexported function `adjust_breaks` from `ggplot2`. There are some complexities when an object-oriented system like S4, ggproto or R6 is used, or when the source code includes compiled C or C++ code, but I haven't come across a situation yet in which I was not able to find the relevant source code after a minute or two with an R console and a good search engine.

Comment: Your advice to add dependencies to `Depends` indiscriminately runs against what most consider to be best practice (e.g. https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html & http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies & https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/8386140). Adding them in `Imports` where feasible is better both b/c it results in less packages being loaded when your package is loaded & b/c it's safer in terms of ensuring the proper versions of functions are called as you expect. The issue can actually be complex, but the answer would be improved with at least a nod to this issue

Comment: You're right of course @duckmayr. The OP is clearly taking the first few steps in package development, and I'm often guilty of trying to make an answer a bit too simple (as long as it works), because the nuances might make the answer off-puttingly complicated for a novice. On the other hand, I don't want to instill sloppy practices. I'll see if I can find a way to cover this without over-complicating. Thanks for taking the time to provide the feedback - it's appreciated.

Comment: No worries! It is a *very* detailed answer already, and you're certainly right that there's only so much detail that can go into a Stack Overflow answer and that too much detail can be off-putting for a novice. Good luck striking the right balance, I just wanted to bring up that issue.